# How to change Firefox settings in WebDriver test?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am running WebDriver tests in Python on Firefox. I have configured my Firefox to make sure all the links of social networking sites are opened in the current tab. I specifically made following two changes

```
browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction then,  change the value to 0 (zero)
browser.link.open_newwindow and change the value to 1 (one)
```

It can be found in https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/970999.

My WebDriver Firefox setup consists of

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

success = True
wd = WebDriver()
wd.implicitly_wait(60)
```

How do I also add the settings to the above setup before starting the test code?

**Edit**

I get the following error when I try to change value of `browser.link.open_newwindow`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Preference     browser.link.open_newwindow may not be overridden: frozen value=2, requested value=1
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences.checkPreference(Preferences.java:223)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Preferences.setPreference(Preferences.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile.setPreference(FirefoxProfile.java:230)
    at tmp.main(tmp.java:21)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the preference using a profile like this.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction", 0);
profile.setPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1);
WebDriver webDriver =  new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

The python code will probably look like this, though I can't test right now.

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile();
profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction", 0);
profile.set_preference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1);
wd =  webdriver.Firefox(profile);
```

Source: [FirefoxDriver Tips & Tricks](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/TipsAndTricks)

Comment: Do you know what is the corresponding import or code in python? Also import in java if I use java

Comment: I just added what I think the python code looks like. I will update later if I can actually test it. Anyone are welcome to correct it if it's wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15787777/how-to-import-and-export-firefox-profile-for-selenium-webdriver-in-python

Comment: I get an error when I try to change the value :( Is there any way I can overwrite them or change permissions

Comment: If they don't allow you to change it, I'm afraid there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Is there any way I can load my preexisting profile into my test. Because I am able to change those values manually.

Comment: These frozen preferences are overwritten by Firefox Driver when it loads, you cannot change them even if you use an existing profile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55115/discussion-between-raju-and-dikei).

Comment: Is the selenium webdriver open source. Where is it hosted if it is. I can probably compile it myself and run.